# How to show model name in android studio when it shows Unknown?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I tried using [this library](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidDeviceNames) to grab the device name, as well as the Build class to show me which device is being used.

With this code

```
String device = DeviceName.getDeviceName();
String buildDevice = Build.MODEL;
System.out.println("DEVICE NAME - " + device);
System.out.println("Using Build class: - " + buildDevice);
```

it shows correctly for my physical Samsung device in Logcat:

```
DEVICE NAME - Samsung SAMSUNG-SM-G891A
Using Build class: - SAMSUNG-SM-G891A
```

But using the Android Studio emulator, it shows (Nexus 5 and 6):

```
DEVICE NAME - Unknown Android SDK built for x86
Using Build class: - Android SDK built for x86
```

I need to get the device name while in the emulator. How can I do this properly, and why is it showing as unknown?

Comment: That would be because an emulator isn't a device... It's an Android SDK environment for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samsung Engineer here,

The reason you aren't seeing a deviceName is that the device name is related to the make and model of the phone

```
Samsung SAMSUNG-SM-G891A  
SM (SMartphone)
G891 (GalaxyS7)
(A refers to ATT carrier)
```

Since you are using the **emulator** you are not using a **real device**.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I will go ahead and accept this as the answer. Thank you.